# lazyload not display images on initial load when entering website aliases

Tags: javascript, html, drupal, lazy-loading

I am new to Drupal.

I have created a Drupal website and install the lazyload plugin in my theme. Lazyload is working fine in my frontpage, but if I enter the website aliases, it does not show any things until I press or scroll.

Comment: Hey, you should provide much more info. With this amount of information one can only hardly guess. Which lazyload plugin are you using? Which aliases you are trying to enter? Are there any errors in your console? Show some of your code, so maybe someone can see the error in it

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely using relative paths for accessing callbacks. Use root relative paths instead (starting with slash "/" sign).